# disable the windows authentication on reporting services

Tags: windows, reporting-services

How can I disable the windows authentication dialog box when opening the RS website http://192.168.2.16/Reports? because 
Is there any way to turn off the windows authentication on accessing http://192.168.2.16/Reports or is there other way to stored user name and passsword